# Google Colab. importar los contenidos a un programa de educación (como lo es CANVAS)

Tags: python, google-colab

Necesito ayuda, he estado creando un contenido en colab, pasa que he tratado de varias formas para importarlo a canvas (plataforma de educación) para que este se vea dentro, pero resulta que de ninguna manera funciona. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de hacerlo? Ya que no me dio con el archivo descargado, tampoco con URL creada desde github.

Importar el contenido mediante URL externa montada en github, usar el URL que nos da la opción compartir.